# How to determine country code in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to assess which country the user is in. In Flutter android/iOS I usually would have used dart:io and collected the info by checking Platform.localeName... but this seems not to work in flutter web as the io package is not supported in web. Do I need to determine it by ip address? Is that possible? Any alternative suggestions of how to get the country code would be grateful

Comment: Did you solve it? :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a while ago, but I used WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale.countryCode from the intl_phone_number_input package. I got the country code number from using this variable I created: final TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(isoCode: '${WidgetsBinding.instance.window.locale.countryCode}');

Comment: Hope that helps. Let me know if you want to know any more